# MPI_Cart_create error

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

I've been having trouble getting the basic mpi_cart_create() function in Fortran working.

The following code

```
  program main
  USE mpi
  implicit none
  integer :: old_comm, new_comm, ndims, ierr
  integer, DIMENSION(1) :: dim_size
  logical ::  reorder
  logical, DIMENSION(1) :: periods

  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  old_comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD
  ndims = 1            
  dim_size(1) = 4   
  periods(1) = .true.  
  reorder = .true.
  call MPI_CART_CREATE(old_comm, ndims, dim_size, periods, reorder, new_comm, ierr)
  call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

  end program
```

Compiled with

```
mpif90 mpitest.f90
```

Yields, during runtime,

> An error occurred in MPI_Cart_create
>
> on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
>
> MPI_ERR_OTHER: known error not in list
>
> MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort

This seems simple, but does anyone recognize the issue?

EDIT: I updated the code (I was a bit hasty in cutting the code down before, thanks for opinting these out) to correct the problems noted below. I think I probably messed up the MPI installation though, since the code will run when compiled with

> ```
>  (when using `use mpi`)
>  mpif90 mpitest3.f90
>  mpirun  -np 4  ./a.out
> ```

OR

> ```
>  (when using `include "mpif.h"`)
>  mpifort mpitest.f90 
>  orterun  -np 4  ./a.out
> ```

If I try to compile with mpifort with the `use mpi` statement I get

> ```
> PI_CART_CREATE(old_comm, ndims, dim_size, periods, reorder, new_comm, ierr)
> ```
>
> Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic
>   'mpi_cart_create' at (1)

And if I mix the compiler and run call (e.g. compile with mpif90 and run with orterun) I get

> Fatal error in PMPI_Cart_create: Invalid argument, error stack:
>   PMPI_Cart_create(315).....: MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ndims=1,
>   dims=0x7fff26671130, periods=0x1c6e300, reorder=1,
>   comm_cart=0x7fff26671124) failed MPIR_Cart_create_impl(191): 
>   MPIR_Cart_create(55)......: Size of the communicator (1) is smaller
>   than the size of the Cartesian topology (4)

Even though the documentation for openmpi states the commands (at least orterun and mpirun) should be synonymous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you have both Open MPI and MPICH (or another MPICH-based implementation) installed. `mpifort` is the generic Fortran compiler wrapper in Open MPI and it seems that it picks module files from MPICH, thus the error when compiling the code with `use mpi`. Your `mpirun` definitely comes from MPICH and it cannot properly launch Open MPI executables. The same is true for `orterun` that comes from Open MPI and it cannot properly launch MPICH executables. In both cases the executables become singletons and each process has its own `MPI_COMM_WORLD` of size 1, therefore it is not possible to create a Cartesian virtual topology with 4 ranks.

The solution is to first purge from the system all MPI implementations and then to install both runtime and development packets from the same implementation, e.g. Open MPI.